# Second monitor extends my desktop, but I want it to mirror it instead

Tags: macos, display, hdmi

I just bought a USB-Type C MultiPort adapter and it works fine, but when I plug in another monitor via HDMI, my desktop is extended. I can not figure out how to make it so that it mirrors my screen instead. I know on windows, you can use `Windows - P` to select this, but how would I do this on mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Apple menu in the top, left corner and open System Preferences. In there, open Displays and click the Arrangement tab. Here you can check the "Mirror Displays" option.